# Changing Slickgrid Tab-Index behaviour

Tags: jquery, slickgrid, tabindex

If i "tab" through my application at some point i will reach a `SlickGrid`. At this point tabbing will result in the single cells getting selected.

What i like to have is that reaching the SlickGrid should get the SlickGrid in focus so i can navigate it with up/down keys as usual but tabbing should result in leaving the SlickGrid and selecting the next element in tab order.

I already tried to set the `tabindex` property of the grids container and also its canvas element but with no success.

Is it possible to disable the tab navigation for single cells in SlickGrid?